# Cross browser solution for submit buttons outside form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, form-submit

I am basically trying to implement this
http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/

I have a cart which is outputting and sandwiched by a html table. Below the table, I currently have my submit button.

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ITEM</th>
        <th>PRICE</th>
        <th>WEIGHT (Kg)</th>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
        <form action='shop.php' id='cart' method='post'>
        <?php  echo $cartOutput; ?>
        </form>

        <tr>
            <td class="totals"><strong>Total</strong></td>
            <td class="totals">&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="totals"><?php if (isset($weightTotal)) { echo $weightTotal . 'kg';} ?> </td>
            <td class="totals"><?php if (isset($quantityTotal)) { echo $quantityTotal; } ?></td>
            <td class="totals"><strong><?php if (isset($cartTotal)) { echo '$' . $cartTotal; } ?></strong></td>
            <td class="totals"></td>
        </tr>   
</tbody>
```

/* code finishing table here */

```
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 remove-padding">

                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" form="cart" name="adjustButton" id="adjust-button">UPDATE CART</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" form="contact" name="order" id="order-button" onclick="confirmOrder()" >ORDER NOW</button>
</div>
```

So because of the way I want the layout to look.. I can't put the buttons inside the form. I want to have the ability to put the update button below the cart. 
Right now the order button is not a submit button but just a button. I can put it beneath its own form section but right now I force it through javascript for a confirmation and then submit the request through JS if they say OK.

I want to keep that function while supporting browsers including IE 9 +10. From what I found `form=""` doesn't work in IE

Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `form` tag outside all 'relevant' content (including submit button(s)):

```
<body>
    <form>
        <table>
        </table>
        <div>
            <button>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

> If the button cannot be inside the form, make the form outside the
>   button.

Comment: This is the simplest and most straightforward solution, and, unless there is some other limitation the OP is not telling us about, this is the way I would go. Otherwise I'd probably go with the [HTML5 shim](https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/)

Comment: Lol, the post's last sentence just sounds like ancient wisdom!

Comment: @BrianBolli it is! with references to mountains and Mahoma :D Good catch!

Answer (score 1):

This should work in all browsers:

```
   document.getElementById('cart').submit();
```

You can put that in the onClick, and wrap it in a function if needed.

Edit: Since the issue (per the comments below) is that you have inputs outside the form: Really the simplest solution, and one that involves no Javascript, is to put the `</form>` at the end of the page (so that all your inputs and buttons will be in the form). But of course this doesn't work if you need to have more than one form on the page, and it might not even be possible depending on how the page is layed out.

Comment: @Robert Rozas, Yes. What did I miss?

Comment: Please read about the form attribute part and you are going to notice that the OP has some inputs outside the form tag and linked that way...but in ie 9+10 that doesn't work...and with your js way, it is not going to submit the inputs linked via form attribute...

Comment: I have tried to put form at the end before but it does not like having all the markup in the middle. It broke the function :(

I don't think I have inputs outside the form. When the order button is pressed, it's pulling information off 1 form. All the other info is stored in the session so I can call that on the next page. In which case... does the submit() work for IE9?

Comment: @Clam, I've not specifically tested it on IE9, but its old old functionality so it definitely should.

Comment: @RobertRozas if there's only one form on the page you can just make sure all the controls _are_ in the form tag by starting the form earlier and ending it later. Nothing forces one to put the form within the table. Make it `<body><form ...> stuff <table> cart etc. </table> ... </form></body>` as Bart shows. There could be some _other_ limitation that the OP is not showing or telling us, but that's another matter.

Comment: thanks for all the help. It looks like the form outside DOES work this time. Something must've been wrong the other time. For the order button, I am still using the JS submit method as proposed by @developerwjk because I want it to call a JS confirm() before executing the submit.

Answer (score 0):

If your submit button is outside the form and you have some input elements outside the form then the simplest way to send this form (without using ajax) would be to make a form and put your submit button in it.

And since your input fields are outside the form you will make a copy of those input fields inside your form and hide them with `display:none;` and when user changes the value of your visible input fields you will use javascript to change the value of the hidden input field.

This way you get to send the form the usual way, without the input fields having to be inside the form itself.....

Comment: @Robert Rozas "OP has some inputs outside the form tag" then this answer would be right?

Comment: you edited you original answer...now it looks more like a comment, but in fact, your aproach should be one of many ways to resolve this, now, can you please provide some working-sample code on how to fill the OP needs?

Comment: is there a way to not involve AJAX? Right now I'm just storing my cart in the session and using it in the next page to send it as an email order. My main problem is having the buttons sit outside the form and being able to submit the form data in IE9+10

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the outside form elements to inside the form and sync them using JS.

http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/y0cmda4o/

```
if ( !('fform' in document.createElement('input')) ) {
    $('input[fform], textarea[fform], select[fform]').on('change', function(e) {
        this.$hidden.val(this.value);
    }).each(function(i, el) {
        var formId = $(el).attr('fform'),
            $form = $('#' + formId),
            $hidden = $('<input name="' + el.name + '" type="hidden">');
        $form.append($hidden);
        el.$hidden = $hidden;
    });
}
```

As you can see, I used the `fform` attribute, to trigger the if statement. Change it to `form` and try it in IE.

**Disclaimer:**

- This won't work with multiple value elements (like `select[multiple]`), or you have to add some serious JS to fake those multiple values.
- This won't send the triggered button value. Normal submit buttons send only their value, and not the other submit buttons'. You could maybe add an `onclick` to handle that... If you use it.